# How to make a browser based IDE to code in the cloud?

Tags: java, ide, cloud, saas

I have read a bit about cloud and browser based IDE's.
I am planning to make a Java based bare bones IDE by integrating a compiler to code in the cloud. This is for educational purpose as I am just determined to learn to develop cloud based IDE.

I want it to be something like eclipse Orion but i want it to allow for coding in java. It should allow users to code, compile and run java programs by directly writing .java files and not by converting the .js files into java files.

Can someone please suggest me an existing cloud that I should use for this. And also, I am just a beginner and I have no clue about how to proceed and the articles that I am required to read.
Please do let me know what I should begin with and the cloud that suits my needs the best.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to develop a browser IDE to code Java?  You will write the server code (in Java also) that runs the IDE?  That would be a massive undertaking.  You should at least use an existing IDE and change its interface from a GUI to a web interface.  However IDE such as NetBeans and Eclipse are very resource intensive and I could not imagine running many instances on a server.

Comment: You plan to develop something like [eclipse orion](http://www.eclipse.org/orion)?

Comment: @home Yes, I think she wants to do something like Eclipse Orion, but instead of javascript, she wants it to be for Java.

Answer (score 0):

For virtual/cloud hosting try one of the following:

- [Rackspace](https://www.rackspace.com)
- [VPS Farm](http://www.vpsfarm.com)

I like vpsfarm because it is cheap and pretty bare bones.

For the IDE itself, I would first create a webapp that can upload and compile and run arbitrary java code, without adding libraries or J2EE. That alone will be a good undertaking for one dev.

Comment: the link to vpsfarm is dead (x_X)

Comment: does it mean that cheap hostings don't last long?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at projects like [Mozilla SkyWriter](http://ace.ajax.org/), which implement the bare bones editing functionality

(There have been a lot of change lately. There seems to have been migrated to [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/))

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Codenvy](http://www.cloudbees.com/platform-service-codenvy.cb) and put your code on a Git repository. Then, you could build automatically once you have done the push using a CI tool like Jenkins. Now, I have an environment in which I use a Jenkins instance as a Service and also a runtime environment so I can get a continuous deployment pipeline. This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyXGc5Uwwao) will show you, in a graphical way, what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

[Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) provides you with a full Ubuntu machine, with root, so it's able to run and do what you want, programming wise.

The reason i'm suggesting Koding though, is that they have a Framework to develop your IDE for the Koding VMs themselves.

The logic here, is that making IDEs is challenging, but the biggest challenges is ensuring security between your IDE users. Using another VM platform would mean that you don't have to manage the security of your VM, and focus entirely on your IDE.

Let me know what you think :)